# Does anyone know how to query all email:password generated users in firebase, with filter by postcode/zipcode?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building Crowdfunding component to create community internet: https://bitbucket.org/tommycp2/integrify-community-internet

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/13KNjgk2awBshC1xk9XoqZWyGpeIqW_apRT5rAHZrizw/edit

Does anyone know how to query all email:password generated users in firebase, with filter by postcode/zipcode?

For some reason I'm getting the feeling that Google has removed this feature.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is no public method in Firebase Authentication (nor has there ever been) to retrieve a list of users. There is a [process to *export* the user data](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/zQW-zV6aqQ4), which we're hoping to clean up in a future release.

But Firebase Authentication doesn't keep the user's postcode/zip code, so even on the exported data you can't filter by that value.